# Can't use @Res() with FilesInterceptor()

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, multer, nestjs

I am trying to upload a file using builtin multer and after then sending the response back to the user for success or failure. It was all going good until today, when I try to upload the Response wont come. after digging a bit I find out that when i use @res with @UploadedFile it does not execute the controller. I am new to nest.js.

Working.

```
@Post('uploads/avatar')
async uploadFile(@Req() req, @UploadedFile() avatar) {
  console.log(req.body);
  if (!req.body.user_id) {
    throw new Error('id params not found.');
  }
  try {
    const resultUpload = await this.userService.uploadUserImage(
      req.body.user_id,
      avatar, 
    ); // returns the url for the uploaded image
    return resultUpload;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
}
```

Not Working.

```
@Post('uploads/avatar')
async uploadFile(@Req() req, @UploadedFile() avatar, @Res() res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  if (!req.body.user_id) {
    throw new Error('id params not found.');
  }
  try {
    const resultUpload = await this.userService.uploadUserImage(
      req.body.user_id,
      avatar,      
    ); // returns the url for the uploaded image
    return resultUpload;
   res.send(resultUpload);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.send(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nest, you should always avoid injecting `@Res` because then you lose a lot of things that make nest so great: interceptors, exception filters,...

And actually, in most cases you don't need `@Res` since nest will automatically handle sending the response correctly.

If you want to send data from a controller method, you can just return the data (`Promises` and `Observables` will be resolved automatically as well). If you want to send an error to the client, you can just throw the corresponding `HttpException`,  e.g. 404 -> `NotFoundException`:

```
@Post('uploads/avatar')
async uploadFile(@Req() req, @UploadedFile() avatar) {
  if (!req.body.user_id) {
    // throw a 400
    throw new BadRequestException('id params not found.');
  }
  try {
    const resultUpload = await this.userService.uploadUserImage(
      req.body.user_id,
      avatar, 
    );
    return resultUpload;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 'image_already_exists') {
      // throw a 409
      throw new ConflictException('image has already been uploaded');
    } else {
      // throw a 500
      throw new InternalServerException();
    }
  }
}
```

If for some reason you have to inject `@Res` here, you cannot use the `FilesInterceptor`. Then you have to configure the `multer` middleware yourself.

---

#### Side note

You can create a custom decorator for accessing the `userId`:

```
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';

export const UserId = createParamDecorator((data, req) => {
  if (!req.body || !req.body.user_id) {
    throw new BadRequestException('No user id given.')
  }
  return req.body.user_id;
});
```

and then use it in your controller method like this:

```
@Post('uploads/avatar')
async uploadFile(@UserId() userId, @UploadedFile() avatar) {
```

Comment: I have doubts about this concept, but this clears them all. Thanks alot.

Comment: What are your doubts? One of the big advantages of nest is that you don't have to handle the response object directly but you can use the higher-level abstractions the framework offers instead.

Comment: I am developing an api. I used @Res in most of the controllers but when I tried it with @UploadedFile() I was not working. I had the doubt that it was because of multer that they implemented in the framework.

Comment: also how can I return a json object using automatic sending response? 
```{ status: "OK", mesage: "Successful"}```

Comment: Just return a javascript object, it will automatically be serialized to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

look, when you are using an interceptor, you are handling (with using `.handle()`) the stream of response (`observable`) not a whole package of it, **but** using express `@Res` actually is somehow getting around the whole flow of response streaming.

this is also explicitly mentioned in [nestjs official documents](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#response-mapping):

> We already know that handle() returns an Observable. The stream
> contains the value returned from the route handler, and thus we can
> easily mutate it using RxJS's map() operator.
>
> WARNING
>
> The response mapping feature doesn't work with the
> library-specific response strategy (using the @Res() object directly
> is forbidden).